# Determing iPad and iPhone models with pop up message

Tags: javascript, php, iphone, ipad

Please forgive my lack of knowledge!

I'm interested in creating a script/web application for my company and I've been diligently looking for the answer to my question.

Is it possible to detect iPhone or iPad models with useragent strings and then display a message to the effect of "You have an iPhone 5C"?... 
If not, what are my other possible options?

I have seen quite a few posts about detecting if it were an iPad or and iPhone for browser formats.. and Also there is a SDK code that emulates the concept I'm trying to achieve.

I'm low on experience... but keen to learn!

Comment: For `iOS` apps, you can easily do it using this one line: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString]`. But I take it you are interested in knowing the device model for the visitors on your website?

Answer (score 0):

The user-friendly name of the models are not available via API.  Apps that I have been involved with that care use data compiled from several websites and build-up some kind of in-app list.  You need both a list of models and their user-friendly name equivalents.  Both are available via google searches.  I don't know of a single, perfectly comprehensive, list, but a bit of searching will find several sites, whose data can be distilled into a single list.

To get the model number of the device to use as a key, the following code is used:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].model
```

Comment: He wants to write a webscript for that! he is not coding an iOS app.

Comment: You may be right, but then objective-c is a funny tag to have.

Comment: Yep I have commented and asked him to confirm what does he really want. From his statement however it is almost obvious that he is trying to get that info from a visit to his site as he is making a web app

Comment: Hey everyone!
Thank you for your very speedy replies.
I'm sorry for the confusing tags, I wasnt too sure so I added the suggested tags.

Ok so NSNoob is on the money as I'm trying to direct less tech savy customers to a page that would be able to detect their exact device model for us so we can know exactly what we're dealing with.

I did find these useragent prefixes And I was hoping that by detecting the useragent prefix in essence I could redirect them to a page specifically for each model..

Apple-iPhone6C1/ iPhone 5S GSM

Comment: Could I potentially use the .htaccess file with specific user agent strings to redirect them to http://5c.website.com - http://iPad3.website.com and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to get the info from a visit to your website. You cannot know exact model of the device with web scripts, at least in my knowledge. But you can determine if the user is using an `iPhone`, `iPad` or `iPod`. Following are two options:

**Javascript:**

```
var Apple = {};
Apple.UA = navigator.userAgent;
Apple.Device = false;
Apple.Types = ["iPhone", "iPod", "iPad"];
for (var d = 0; d < Apple.Types.length; d++) {
    var t = Apple.Types[d];
    Apple[t] = !!Apple.UA.match(new RegExp(t, "i"));
    Apple.Device = Apple.Device || Apple[t];
}

// is this an Apple device?
alert(
    "Apple device? " + Apple.Device +
    "niPhone? " + Apple.iPhone +
    "niPod? " + Apple.iPod +
    "niPad? " + Apple.iPad
);
```

**PHP script:**

```
// Apple detection array
$Apple = array();
$Apple['UA'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$Apple['Device'] = false;
$Apple['Types'] = array('iPhone', 'iPod', 'iPad');
foreach ($Apple['Types'] as $d => $t) {
    $Apple[$t] = (strpos($Apple['UA'], $t) !== false);
    $Apple['Device'] |= $Apple[$t];
}

// is this an Apple device?
echo
    "<p>Apple device? ", ($Apple['Device'] ? 'true' : 'false'),
    "</p>n<p>iPhone? ", ($Apple['iPhone'] ? 'true' : 'false'),
    "</p>n<p>iPod? ", ($Apple['iPod'] ? 'true' : 'false'),
    "</p>n<p>iPad? ", ($Apple['iPad'] ? 'true' : 'false'),
    '</p>';
```

For more information, read [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/identify-apple-iphone-ipod-ipad-visitors/).

Since your tags and statement is a bit confusing, just on the off-chance that If you are using iOS sdk and building an iOS app, you can simply get the model from one line like:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString]
```